# vb.net get filename list from wildcard

Tags: vb.net, filenames, wildcard

I have string say "c:\debug\ *.txt"
In Debug folder there are severeal .txt files , say test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt .

How can I get from this string c:\debug\ *.txt an array of wildcard files?

```
a(0)=c:\debug\test1.txt
a(1)=c:\debug\test2.txt
a(2)=c:\debug\test3.txt
```

It is also possible that the string would be something like "C:\logs\12*\ *.log"

```
a(0)=C:\logs\120114\01.log
a(0)=C:\logs\120114\02.log
a(0)=C:\logs\120114\03.log
```

etc.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you. It'll handle wildcards in directory part and filename part

```
Private Function GetFiles(ByVal Path As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim drivePart As String, dirPart As String, filePart As String

    drivePart = Path.Substring(0, Path.IndexOf("\") + 1)
    dirPart = Path.Substring(Path.IndexOf("\") + 1, Path.LastIndexOf("\") - Path.IndexOf("\") - 1)
    filePart = Path.Substring(Path.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)


    Dim directories As New List(Of String)
    Dim files As New List(Of String)


    '' Walk directory tree finding matches
    '' This should handle wildcards in any part of the path
    Dim currentIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim directoryMatch As String() = dirPart.Split("\")
    For Each directory As String In directoryMatch
        WalkDirectories(drivePart, directories, directoryMatch, currentIndex)
        currentIndex += 1
    Next

    For Each directory As String In directories
        files.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, filePart))
    Next


    Return files

End Function

Private Sub WalkDirectories(ByVal dirPart As String, ByVal directories As List(Of String), ByVal directoryMatch As String(), ByVal currentIndex As Integer)

    If currentIndex = directoryMatch.Length Then Return

    For Each d As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dirPart, directoryMatch(currentIndex))
        directories.Add(d)


        WalkDirectories(System.IO.Path.Combine(dirPart, d), directories, directoryMatch, currentIndex + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit: just noticed that it wont handle UNC paths but it should be pretty easy to modify for that if you need to
Editted again to handle multiple directory levels and wildcards at multiple levels (eg C:\debug\12*\log1*\errors*.txt

Comment: Why go through the hassle of using substring to get the portions of the filename when you can use the methods of system.io.path (Path.GetPathRoot, Path.GetDirectoryName, Path.GetFileName)?  They are much clearer and easier to use and not prone to error.

Comment: Thank you all for ideas, but what I could not find and had problems with is that for specific situations I can code and it will work.

But I needed code for general wildcard analasys. Like in windows CMD when you write * it undestands that it is a wildcard and based on that goes to path. 

Your code will only work if there are two subfolders but what if they are 5?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway the question required the use of wildcards in the path, your method wouldnt handle that

Comment: @user3360710 you'd have to split the dirPart on the '\' character and use GetDirectories on each segment

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Given a path string of "c:\debug\*.txt", your code produces the same strings as mine except that GetDirectoryName also includes the drive specifier so that one may need adjustment.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway The question also mentioned paths including withcards in the directory name (eg c:\debug\12*\). The only way to do that would be to search for each directory matching that then searching each of those directories for matching files. Given a path string of C:\debug*\ *.txt, my code works fine but as the OP pointed out it only works for a to a certain directory depth

Comment: KEV I tested the code and your solutions is what I need. In UNC paths it removes the Host in final Output, BUT i just need the files so fo me it doesent matter.

Comment: Update KEV could you add UNC support? It trows exception saying that it needs full UNC path \\server\share and using the existing code I can't seem to get it working. I tried to make so that the drive part is correct \\server\ but still it had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code:

```
Dim Path As String = "C:\debug"
Dim Dir As New DirectoryInfo(Path)
Dim q = (From x In Dir.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) Select x.FullName).ToArray
```

You might need to

```
Import System.IO
Import System.Linq
```

Basically your key for the requirement is **SearchOption.AllDirectories** which iterates through sub directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetFiles from My.Computer.System and the ReadOnlyCollection(of String) from the system.collections.objectModel import and a searchoption as desired (top or all)

```
sPath = "C:\debug"     ' your desired path
sFile1 = "t*.txt"      ' your desired search pattern with * wildcard
sFile2 = "test?.txt"   ' your desired search pattern with ? wildcard  

dim lstFiles as system.collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(of String) = My.Computer.Filesystem.GetFiles(sPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, sFile1)

'lstfiles contains all the files that match your selection 
'if you really need an array you can convert the list to array here

dim i as integer = 0
for each sFile as string in lstfiles
    a(i)=sfile
    i+=1
next
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'Like' keyword:

```
  ' For your example, call this function with root = "C:\logs" and wild = "12*\*.log"

  Friend Function GetMyFiles(root As String, wild As String, Optional allowsub As Boolean = True) As List(Of String)

    Dim a As New List(Of String), pattern As String

    ' ensure root ends with a \
    If Not root.EndsWith("\") Then root &= "\"

    ' the extra * allows for subdirectories in between, if required
    pattern = root & If(allowsub, "*", "") & wild

    For Each f As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(root, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
      If f Like pattern Then a.Add(f)
    Next

    Return a

  End Function
```

Of course, if you hit a protected system directory, it'll fail.

This function is just to demonstrate the 'Like' keyword.

It will work if 'root' isn't a drive root (e.g. C:).

Done properly, a separate function would collect directories first, each tested for access permissions in a Try/Catch block. Here's how that looks:

```
  Friend Function GetAllAccessibleDirs(ByRef Dir As String, Optional inclDir As Boolean = True, Optional Sort As Boolean = False) As List(Of String)
    Dim D As New List(Of String), Q As New Queue(Of String), dummy As DirectoryInfo, s As String
    If inclDir Then D.Add(Dir)
    Q.Enqueue(Dir)
    While Q.Count
      For Each s In GetTopLevelDirs(Q.Dequeue)
        Try
          dummy = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo(s)
          D.Add(s)
          Q.Enqueue(s)
        Catch
          ' Inaccessible folder
        End Try
      Next
    End While
    If Sort AndAlso D.Count Then D.Sort()
    Return D
  End Function

  Friend Function GetTopLevelDirs(ByRef dir As String) As List(Of String)
    Try
      Return My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(dir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly).ToList
    Catch
      Return New List(Of String)
    End Try
  End Function
```